# In Angular 2 , Function decorator is not working

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#item of items">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
```

Comment: I guess you need to provide more information about your problem for other s to be able to help. Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set this in `tsconfig.json`

```
{ 
"compilerOptions": 
   { 
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true 
  }
}
```